# Additional Unpacking Generalizations (PEP 448) with variable number of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking, pep, pep448

The acceptance of **[`PEP 448`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)** has introduced ***Additional Unpacking Generalizations*** in `Python 3.5`.

For example:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]

# unpack both iterables in a list literal
>>> joinedList = [*l1, *l2]
>>> print(joinedList)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to do similar thing with a list of lists?

This code does not work:

> SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension

```
# List of variable size
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
joined_list = [*l for l in list_of_lists]
```

Of course, you could do the following but that looks less elegant and does not look efficient:

```
# List of variable size
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
joined_list = list()
for l in list_of_lists:
    joined_list += l
```

Comment: No. Use either [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) or a nested list comprehension `[x for l in list_of_lists for x in l]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about going old school: [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

#### Code:

```
joined_list = sum(list_of_lists, [])
```

#### Test Code:

```
# List of variable size
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
joined_list = sum(list_of_lists, [])
print(joined_list)
```

#### Results:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to discourage using `sum` here, as it's a form of [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm). `sum` actually forbids it with `str`; they didn't try to block all sequence uses to avoid slowing down `sum` trying to block every misuse, but it's still a bad idea.

The problem is that it means you build progressively larger temporary `list`s each time, throwing away the last temporary after building the next one by copying *everything* you've seen so far, plus new stuff, over and over. If the first list has a million items in it, and you have ten more `list`s to concatenate onto it, you're copying at least 10 million elements (even if the other ten `list`s are empty). Your original code was actually better, in that using the `+=` operator performed in-place extension, keeping the worst case performance in the `O(n)` (for `n` elements across all `list`s) range, rather than `O(n*m)` (for `n` elements across `m` `list`s).

It also has the problem of only working for one consistent type; if some inputs are `list`s, some `tuple`s, and some generators, `sum` won't work (because `list.__add__` won't accept non-`list` operands for the other side).

So don't do that. This is [what `itertools.chain` and it's alternate constructor, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` were made for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
joined_list = list(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
```

It's guaranteed `O(n)`, works with any iterables you throw at it, etc.

Yes, obviously if you've just got three `list`s of three elements a piece, it hardly matters. But if the size of the input iterables or the number of iterables is arbitrarily large, or the types aren't consistent, `chain` will work, `sum` won't.